# Capture barcode scanned in .NET MAUI Android

Tags: android, .net, barcode, maui

in MAUI Android Application,how to receive a system broadcast for every barcode scanned,i need this function,please tell me,thank you everyone

Comment: Are you using a device with a built in scanner?  Your question is very light on details of your use case

Comment: yes, jason  i am using a device with a built in scanner

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the manual for your device to determine what integrations it provides for the scanner.  If you need additional help, please [edit] your question to include the relevant details.  Also take the time to read [ask]

Comment: my device is a PDA, i mean its a Industrial Mobile Data Terminal  it has a scanner in the top of device  i am using maui to develop a app for this device

Comment: Again, YOU need to read the docs for YOUR device.  AFAIK there is no universal API that all hardware scanners use.  In my experience most just act as a keyboard wedge.